# The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded, Encoding done by JsonWebtoken

Tags: local-storage, json-web-token

which way is the correct one for decoding tokens in the client side that are encoded using the node jsonwebtoken module, this is how am creating the token

```
let token = jwt.sign({
   my_data: data,
   exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000) 
}, "SECRET"); 

res.status(200).json({jwt_token: token });
```

And in the client side, I save the token using localStorage like:

```
let token = server_response_token;
window.localStorage.setItem('client_token', token );
```

And then I try to decode the token from the local storage like:

```
let payload = window.localStorage.getItem('client_token').split('.')[1];
let decoded = window.atob(payload);
```

But with that I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
```

Where am I going wrong here, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use of `atob()` function for decode your **JWT-TOKEN**.
angular have `jwt-decode` component for this issue.

you have to install this library:

> npm install jwt-decode

and import this to your component that you want to decode like:

> import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

Now take your token and decode that.

```
  getUserProfile() {
    const idToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    return jwt_decode(idToken);
  }
```

Now you have user profile.